# How to find RowCount of a table which pasted from web to excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-web-query

im recieving a table from web in excel with the code below

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;some url")
    .WebSelectionType = "xlSpecifiedTables"
    .WebTables = "10"
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SaveData = True
End With
```

but also i wanna get the row count from that table i got.
so how can i achive that?

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;some url")
    .LineCount 'is it smt like this???????
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply use something like `Range("B3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` ?
Note that you can't know the # rows to be downloaded before actually downloading them, and since you are using `.BackgroundQuery = True`, you don't really know when the download is complete...

Comment: What if the region that i want has some empty cells i mean entire row has empty cells or entire column has empty cells which are used like a seperator for cell values, could stop the function counting the range right? Than the range command would not work unless i use smt like: i = i + 1 and then Range("B" & i).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count whenever it founds empty cells and if empty cells occurs more than once would stop the loop.. yea that may work.. unless u have a better solution for empty cells i can use this.. anyways its a good call so thanks also +1 for simplicity.